# High time complexity reduction of the matlab code

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to run this piece of code in matlab but it has a high complexity 
despite that matlab is very slow with for loops.
Could somewhat please help me to optimize the code below.

```
for k=1:th
    for i=1:D-1
        for j=i+1:D
            if(dist(j,k)>dist(i,k))
                t=ClassP1(k,i);
                ClassP1(k,i)=ClassP1(k,j);
                ClassP1(k,j)=t;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

where

size(ClassP1)=20x4276

size(dist)=4276x20

Thank you a lot in advance

Rinadi

Comment: Newer versions of Matlab are not slow in loops. Is there any actual problem with the time taken or is it just that you'd like to improve the solution?

Comment: It won't increase performance much, but a quick tip: Swapping two elements: `ClassP1(k,[ii,jj]) = ClassP1(k,[jj,ii])`.

Comment: grantnz:I am more concern about the for loops is there any way how to not use them. Since Matlab is JAVA based it isn't that fast with loops and there are 3 for loops nested. That slows me down a lot.
@Robert Thank you I will try that one as well right now.

Comment: Matlab isn't java based. It just uses java for its UI.

Comment: Thanks then, I thought it was java based. :(

Comment: Just checking: Is `th=20` and `D=4276`?  It's not explicitly stated, but seems apparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to remove the outer loop over `k` like so (untested since I don't have your data, might need some tweaking):

```
for i = 1:D-1
    for j = i+1:D
        iswap = find(dist(j, 1:th) > dist(i, 1:th));
        ClassP1(iswap, [i, j]) = ClassP1(iswap, [j, i])
    end
end
```

I am not sure if this saves a lot in readability or in speed.

But what is your goal? It seems that you are doing something like sorting the matrix `ClassP1` based on the matrix `dist` (but not exactly). Maybe there is a better solution  using `[~, idx] = sort(dist)` and then `ClassP1(??, idx) = whatever`.